# how to change the value of user.identity.name

Tags: asp.net

I think this is a very fundamental question - but i am not sure how to do it.

I am trying to test an application with different user login ID's (because these users have different roles).The application uses the login information of the system user and has no login of its own. The `user.identity.name` is used to get the value. However I would like to override this value to test for different user logins. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always mock it with something like Moq

```
Mock<ControllerContext> ControllerContextMock;
string UserName = "TestUser";
ControllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
ControllerContextMock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(UserName);
```

this is how I do my unit/behavior testing

per my Comment below I'm adding a wrapper around the get user Name

```
public string OverideName;

private string GetUserName()
{
    string name;
    if(OverideName != null && OverideName.Langth>0)
    {
       name = OverideName;
    }else
    {
       name = User.Identity.Name;
    }
    return name;
}
```

For most older asp.net web form testing this is really the only way to test stuff

Comment: Will this change the value in user.identity.name ? Because eventually I am trying to check user.IsinRole(---)? Also can you re-write this for vb  without using linq and lamba and controller context? The existing code is written in vs 2003 asp.net

Comment: ControllerContext is cool for MVC.  I don't think that will work for your scenario.

Comment: .net 1.1 gets tricky, in that case your best option would be to add a wrapper around getting the User.Identity.Name that provides the override.

Comment: Thankyou ! I will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

When you set your authentication ticket, change it there.  I'm assuming it's using Forms Auth (logging in as user).

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("Joe",false);
```

If using Windows Authentication you could use impersonation.

Another alternative, if using Windows Authentication, is to modify your browser setting to prompt you for a login.  Then login as the different user.

Comment: That would work for me, but how do you know that this guy's name is `Joe`? :)

Comment: Ha, do you have the users information from a login field or something?  How exactly are you authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wanting to do the same.

My thoughts are to create a "change identity" page (only accessible by those with admin roles in my application). They can then choose to be a different person / role for the purpose of testing the application.

Each page in my application tests to see if a session set user id and role is valid (set on first use of the application) and loads the page to show the information / functionality that that user / role is meant to see. So this "change identity" function would set the session user id and role to that of the user under test, and allow the person testing to behave as if they are the other person. Also providing a reset option to reset yourself back to you.

Answer (score -1):

Simpliest solution is when user updates name - log him out, and ask for login.
its work for me

Comment: Please don't add comments in here. These are low quality that they can be in comments section. Once you have enough reputation you can do that.